# Having issue in multiple image upload? db image attached

Tags: php, image, using, uploading

```
<form name="property" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select Image
<input type="file" name="upload[]"  multiple="multiple" id="image"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" style="width:200px; height:30px;" />
</form>
```

MY Php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) 
{
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
if ($tmpFilePath != "")
{
$newFilePath[] = "upload/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
$values_insert = implode(',', $newFilePath);
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) 
{
$date=date("Y-m-d");
}
}
}
$d=mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties (iname,cdate) VALUES('".$values_insert."',NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

[image: Here It shows the upload foldername and image name, I want only image name sperated by comma, please see the image]

Note:
    In database the path upload directory folder and image image is going to database, I want only image name separated by comma. for example the expected output is Chrysanthemum.jpg,Desert.jpg. I don't know what is the problem. please guide me.kindly look at my code and image attachment details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing this'll do fyi - indenting code would help people read and help you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) 
    {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if ($tmpFilePath != "")
    {
    $newFilePath = "upload/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
    $newFilePath2[] =  $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
    $values_insert = implode(',', $newFilePath2);
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) 
    {
    $date=date("Y-m-d");
    }
    }
    }
    $d=mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties (iname,cdate) VALUES('".$values_insert."',NOW())") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```